# Get xpath to incorrect element of xml. Python, lxml

Tags: python, xml, xpath, xsd, lxml

I'm using python to work with xml document, with the help of lxml package. An xsd scheme is used to validate that document. When an error occures, validator raises ParseError with a position of incorrect element. But what I need is an xpath to that element. Is there any way to get it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the validator give you the position of incorrect element (for example : 8), you could try to access it with the following XPath expression :

```
(//*)[position()=8]
```